# CSS background-position top right corner

Tags: html, css

I want [image: icon] background image on a button to appear at the top right corner.

I successfully used `background-position: bottom top 100px` to move the image to the top, but I have been unsuccessful moving the image to the right.

Is there something similar to `background-position: bottom top 100px, right 900px` that might help produce the desired results?

```
#AddNewMeetingButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(Images/add_icon_48x48.png);
    background-position: bottom top 100px, right 800px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 190px;
    width: 915px;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Tried `float:right;`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like this

```
background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW9aK.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 48px 48px;
background-position: right 10px top 10px;
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0f1vug25/)

[**MDN Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)

> `background-position:<position>` where:
>
> `<position>` is one to four values representing a 2D position regarding the edges of the element's box. Relative or absolute offsets can be given. Note that the position can be set outside of the element's box.

So:

```
background-position: right 10px top 10px;
```

puts the image at the top / right but 10px away from the right edge and 10px from the top edge

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
background-position: right top;
```

If you need a margin add it to the image.

Comment: Almost, but margin won't affect a background image.

Comment: I mean the image itself, no css margin. But your answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

Use the shorthand property to set the background properties in one declaration:

```
background: #ffffff url("img_tree.png") no-repeat right top;
```

Using this shorthand property you can order as elaborated in detailed below

1.) background-color : 3 type of valid color formating like "red", HEX value #000000,  an RGB value like "rgb(255,0,0)"

2.) background-image : url

3.) background-repeat : repeat|repeat-x|repeat-y|no-repeat|initial|inherit;

4.) background-attachment : scroll|fixed|local|initial|inherit;

5.) background-position : the value combination as shown below

left top

left center

left bottom

right top

right center

right bottom

center top

center center

center bottom

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
float:right;
```

That should do it, otherwise I think you have to set position property to "relative" for the parent element of the button element.

Try the float:right property first.